# Count string followed by separate string occurrences in r

Tags: r

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of a string followed by another string in r. I cannot seem to get the regex worked out to count this correctly.

As an example:

```
v <- c("F", "F", "C", "F", "F", "C", "F", "F")
b <- str_count(v, "F(?=C)")
```

I would like b to tell me how many times string F was followed by string C in vector v (which should equal 2).

I have successfully implemented str_count() to count single strings, but I cannot figure out how to count string followed by a different string.

Also, I found that in regex (?=...) should indicated "followed by" however this does not seem to be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have one string. You have individual strings. Her you can test if `F` is followed by `C` by shifting using `[` for subsetting.

```
sum(v[-length(v)] == "F" & v[-1] == "C")
#sum(v == "F" & c(v[-1] == "C", FALSE)) #Alternative
#[1] 2
```

To use `stringr::str_count` you can `paste` `v` to one string.

```
stringr::str_count(paste(v, collapse = ""), "F(?=C)")
#[1] 2
```

And for rows of a `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(42)
v <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("F", "C"), 25, TRUE), 5))
stringr::str_count(apply(v, 1, paste, collapse = ""), "F(?=C)")
#[1] 1 1 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` from dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)
sum(v == "C" & lag(v) == "F", na.rm = TRUE)
```

(The `na.rm = TRUE` is because the first value of `lag(v)` is NA).

---

Your comment notes that you're also interested in applying this across each row of a data frame. This can be done by pivoting the data to be longer, then applying a grouped mutate, then pivoting the data to be wider again. On an example dataset:

```
example <- tibble(id = 1:3,
                  s1 = c("F", "F", "F"),
                  s2 = c("C", "F", "C"),
                  s3 = c("C", "C", "F"),
                  s4 = c("F", "C", "C"))

example %>%
  pivot_longer(s1:s4) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(fc_count = sum(value == "C" & lag(value) == "F", na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
     id fc_count s1    s2    s3    s4   
  <int>    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1        1 F     C     C     F    
2     2        1 F     F     C     C    
3     3        2 F     C     F     C
```

Note that this assumed the data had something like an `id` column that uniquely identifies each original row. If it doesn't, you can add one with `mutate(id = row_number())` first.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly with my example. 

Quick follow-up question, my actual application counts occurrences of F then C over rows of a dataframe (e.g., row 1 c("F", "F", "C", "F", "F", "C", "F", "F"), row 2 c("C", "C", "C", "F", "F", "C", "F", "F"), etc.). 

I am having trouble translating your solution to counting this same value per row of a dataframe. Any suggestions you might have would be great!

Comment: Ah: for that you have two options: you could turn the data frame into a matrix and use `apply()` to apply the function on each row, or use `pivot_longer` to reshape the data then group by and summarize. I prefer the pivoting approach, but it mostly depends on one question: do you have other columns in the data besides the F’s and C’s?

Comment: Ok great! Yes, I do have other columns in the dataframe.

Comment: @KelseyUrgo I think my edit might answer your question, please let me know if it works!

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Once I got everything organized the code executed with desired output. Also, I need to convert from using dataframes to tibbles, they are very intuitive and useful. Thanks again!